# Bootstrap col size depending on ng-repeat items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to populate my site with ng-repeat images. I wanted to make something like if there is only one image in images, it's going to get 1 full row(col-xs-12), if there will be 2 images, they are going to load as col-xs-6, up to maximum 6 images(col-xs-2 per image).

Is it even possible to play it like that? I wanted to list them as ul>li>img + description.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write like this

```
  <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="image in images" ng-class="{'col-xs-12':images.length== 1 ,  }">
       </li>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's actually possible using the [`ng-class` directive of Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

What you can do is call a function with the number of images you get that will return the corresponding `Bootstrap class`.

Comment: okay, seems like yours and hadiJZ example would do great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this :

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="image in images" class="col-xs-{{Math.floor(12 / images.length)}}">
     </li>
</ul>
```

this way, the width of the column will be automatically set. The problem is if you have more than 12 images, the width will be 0.